# Decorator Pattern, compiler doesn't allow type propagation

Tags: java, decorator

I am trying to implement the decorator pattern, here my specfication :

```
public abstract class Menu{ //propagate the type
}
```

And

```
public class Sandwich extends Menu{ // Concrete class which is a Menu

}
```

And

```
public abstract class Extra extends Menu{

    Menu menu;

    public Extra(Menu menu){ // the constructor takes a Menu type
       this.menu=menu;
    }
}
```

The problem is why the compiler doesn't allow this :

```
public class Test {
  Menu sand1 = new Sandwich();
  sand1 = new Extra(sand1); //It's fine for the compiler

  Sandwich sand = new Sandwich();
  sand = new Extra (sand);// Compiler cries here !!
}
```

Sandwich `IS-A Menu` via inheritence, `Extra`'s constructor takes a `Menu` so why the compiler isn't happy?

Compiler message : `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Extra to Sandwich`

Thanks for your clarifications.

Comment: An `Extra` is not a `Sandwich`...What does the compiler say _exactly_?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I added the compiler message

Comment: Well there you go, I don't understand your confusion. The problem is spelled out in the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine this case ( that sandwich has some methods):

```
 public class Sandwich extends Menu{
  public void addSalad(){
  //...
  }
 }
```

So now youre doing this:

```
 Sandwich sand = new Sandwich();
 sand.addSalad();//works

 sand = new Extra (sand);//imagine this doesnt throw errs
 sand.addSalad();//will fail as sands not a sandwich anymore
```

The upper code will fail. Therefore, youre not allowed to assign a non Sandwich to sand.

Comment: You convinced me but in my case the 2 classes share a same method that I would like to get the result after the `new Extra(sand)`.

Comment: @akuma8 then that should be a Menu method. And sand should be a menu, not a sandwich

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not passing `sand` to the `Extra` constructor, the problem is trying to assign the `new Extra(sand)` to type `Sandwich`.

Comment: I see, but why? Since `Sandwich is a Menu` and `Extra` too.

Comment: Just because two classes inherit from the same superclass doesn't mean they are same.  Just think, a `Dog` is an `Animal` and a `Cat` is an `Animal`, but assigning a `Dog` variable to an instance of type `Cat` would make no sense